# Is it possible to change the position of the Facebook box that appears after liking a page?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like, positioning, facebook-likebox

The like button works fine, the recommendation works fine, but there's an issue: the like button is positioned on the right side of the page (which is intended), but when the button is clicked, it opens a box that exceeds the boundaries of the browser, to the right.
Example (with me in the Santa's hat as a doubtful bonus):

[image: example image]

I've tried controlling the position using css, with no success. How can i proceed?

TL;DR
I need that recommendation box on the left, not on the right as it is now.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the css? The problem is definitely in there. Why don't you check it with firebug? It's the easiest way to see where the guilty code is

Comment: You can see the live example here: http://www.promundoeventos.com.br/teste/

Comment: I had misunderstood the question, I edited it now!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the css. Try using firebug to inspect the elements, you can change properties live to see which ones are the ones giving you the headache.

(edited)

The sidebar container is `position:absolute`, and has `right:0`. There's your problem.

```
#sidebarSocialetContainer {
right: 0px;
margin-right: 10px;
width: auto;
margin-top: -39px;
position: absolute;
}
```

So, if you put `left:0` instead of `right:0` you'll see the bar in the opposite side.

Comment: Yes, but then the whole element goes to the left. If you click on the Like button you'll see the Facebook comment box opening to the right...i need only that box positioned to the left of the like button.

Comment: can you upload the file again?